# Adding text between data column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
   Names    Values  TC
   Ram      2      TC Count
   pechi    2      TC Count
   Sunil    1      TC Count
   Ravi     1      TC Count
   sri      1      TC Count
```

I want to add some texts between the data columns

I tried df.join but not wot working fine,

My expected output is,

df,

```
Names    Values  
Ram      val2balTCcount   
pechi    val2balTCcount         
Sunil    val1balTCcount         
Ravi     val1balTCcount         
sri      val1balTCcount
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- convert all numeric columns to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)
- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) whitespaces by empty space

---

```
df['Values'] = 'val' + df['Values'].astype(str) + 'bal' + df['TC'].str.replace('\s+', '') 
print (df)
   Names          Values        TC
0    Ram  val2balTCCount  TC Count
1  pechi  val2balTCCount  TC Count
2  Sunil  val1balTCCount  TC Count
3   Ravi  val1balTCCount  TC Count
4    sri  val1balTCCount  TC Count
```

And if need remove `TC` column use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['Values'] = 'val' + df['Values'].astype(str) + 'bal' + df.pop('TC').str.replace('\s+', '')
print (df)
   Names          Values
0    Ram  val2balTCCount
1  pechi  val2balTCCount
2  Sunil  val1balTCCount
3   Ravi  val1balTCCount
4    sri  val1balTCCount
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.str.cat` and `pd.Series.apply` with `str.format`

```
df.drop('TC', 1).assign(
    Values=df.Values.apply('val{}bal'.format)
             .str.cat(df.TC.str.replace(' ', '')))

   Names          Values
0    Ram  val2balTCCount
1  pechi  val2balTCCount
2  Sunil  val1balTCCount
3   Ravi  val1balTCCount
4    sri  val1balTCCount
```

---

Though the `pd.Series.cat` can be replaced with `+`

```
df.drop('TC', 1).assign(
    Values=df.Values.apply('val{}bal'.format)
          + df.TC.str.replace(' ', ''))

   Names          Values
0    Ram  val2balTCCount
1  pechi  val2balTCCount
2  Sunil  val1balTCCount
3   Ravi  val1balTCCount
4    sri  val1balTCCount
```